# Анализ слов mp3 python

Tags: python, mp3

Есть Google Speech Api которое распознает твою речь с микрофона. Если ли похожая функция, но только с mp3 или ogg файла? Можно и другие языки.

Comment: проигрывай mp3  в эту апишку.